# How to get an interpolated pixel value in openlayers?

Tags: javascript, image, openlayers

My goal is to display an image, and display the value of the image (e.g. RGB values) at the location of the mouse cursor.  Because this image is low resolution, I would like to display it with interpolation (this works), and I would like to display the interpolated pixel value (this does not work).

There is a very similar example online that discusses interpolation:  https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/interpolation.html.  But when I replace the source with a static image, the pixel values displayed are not interpolated.  They step discretely from one region to the next.

I can create a minimum working example here, running locally with npm start:

```
import './style.css';
import {Map, View} from 'ol';
import ImageLayer from 'ol/layer/Image';
import Static from 'ol/source/ImageStatic';
import { Projection } from 'ol/proj';
import {getCenter} from 'ol/extent.js';

// now make my maps
const extent = \[0,0,32,32\];
// start with a projection
// this tells us how to interpret coordinates
// if we have more than one projection, we can do reprojection
const projection = new Projection({
code: 'image',
units: 'pixels',
extent: extent,
});

// in a view we have another projection.  We can use this to "reproject" if necessary
const view = new View({
center: getCenter(extent),
zoom: 2,
maxZoom: 8,
projection: projection,
});

// image source needs a projection to tell us how to interpet the layout
// it needs an image extent to tell us where to put it
const image_source = new Static({
crossOrigin: '',  
url: 'image0.png',
projection: projection,
imageExtent: extent, // Extent of the image in map coordinates. This is the \[left, bottom, right, top\] map coordinates of your image.
interpolate: true,
});

// the image layer will have a source, it doesn't need anything else
const image_layer = new ImageLayer({
//extent: extent, // The bounding extent for layer rendering. The layer will not be rendered outside of this extent.
source: image_source
});

// has a target, a view, and layers
const map3 = new Map({
target: 'map3',
view: view,
layers: \[image_layer\],
});

// create a hover
const info1 = document.getElementById('info1');

const display = function (evt) {
if (evt.dragging) {
return;
}

const pixel = image_layer.getData(evt.pixel);
info1.innerText = pixel
? pixel
: '-';

};
map3.on('pointermove',display);
```

html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


  
    
    
    
    Using OpenLayers with Vite
  
  

    <div id="map3" style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 50%; width: 50%;"></div>
    
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; bottom: 0%; width: 50%;">
      <label>
        Value
        <span id="info1">-</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    
    
    <script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
```

image0.png is a local 32x32 image.

I would expect the value displayed to match the pixel that appears on the screen (like the example in open layers documentation).  But instead, the value displayed matches the pixel values of the un-interpolated image.

Answer (score 2):

You can place the layer inside an `ol/source/Raster`

```
const image_layer = new ImageLayer({
  source: new RasterSource({
    sources: [image_source],
    operationType: 'image',
    operation: function (images) {
      return images[0];
    },
  }),
});
```

Working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><html lang="en">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v8.2.0/dist/ol.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v8.2.0/ol.css">
<style>
    html, body, .map {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #map {
        position: relative;
    }
    #info {
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background: white;
        color: black;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" class="map"><pre id="info"/></div>
<script>
  const ImageLayer = ol.layer.Image;
  const Map = ol.Map;
  const Projection = ol.proj.Projection;
  const RasterSource = ol.source.Raster;
  const Static = ol.source.ImageStatic;
  const View = ol.View;

    const extent = [0, 0, 32, 32];
    const projection = new Projection({
      code: 'image',
      units: 'pixels',
      extent: extent,
    });

    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = 32;
    canvas.height = 32;
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const imageData = context.createImageData(32, 32);
    const data = imageData.data;

    for (let j = 0; j < 32; ++j) {
      for (let i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
        const offset = (j * 32 + i) * 4;
        data[offset] = i * 8;
        data[offset + 1] = 0;
        data[offset + 2] = j * 8;
        data[offset + 3] = 255;
      }
    }
    context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

    const image_source = new Static({
      crossOrigin: '',  
      url: canvas.toDataURL(),
      projection: projection,
      imageExtent: extent,
      interpolate: true,
    });

    const image_layer = new ImageLayer({
      source: new RasterSource({
        sources: [image_source],
        operationType: 'image',
        operation: function (images) {
          return images[0];
        },
      }),
    });

    const map = new Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [image_layer],
      view: new View({
        center: [16, 16],
        zoom: 2,
        projection: projection,
      }),
    });

    const info = document.getElementById('info');

    const display = function (evt) {
      if (evt.dragging) {
        return;
      }
      const pixel = image_layer.getData(evt.pixel);
      info.innerText = pixel ? pixel : '-';
    };
    map.on('pointermove', display);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The example you linked relates to reprojection, which creates a new tile grid as described in https://openlayers.org/doc/tutorials/raster-reprojection.html  The interpolate option there determines if pixels can be  interpolated when creating the new tiles.

Comment: Thanks, this does work.  It seems odd though, to have this nesting of image layer -> raster source -> image layer -> image source.  Could you say anything about why this design is necessary or expected?

Comment: It is not necessary to specify the layer in this case as it will create one by default based on the source type - an inner layer is only necessary if you need event handling or styling, such as vector sources, heatmap or webgl, for example https://deploy-preview-13647--ol-site.netlify.app/en/latest/examples/contour-interpolation.html